# WP_User_Query not displaying any user

Tags: wp-user-query

I dont understand what is wrong my code is just not working, I have tried with different $args but still no user displays.

Following is my code:

```
$args = array(
    'role__in' => array('Subcriber', 'Editor','Administrator'),
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$reslult = $user_query->results;
// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

Result is always no user found.

Comment: `Subcriber` is spelt wrong. Needs to be `Subscriber`. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

See the example code on this [URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#User_Role_Parameter)

Correct the spelling `Subscriber`